# Como adicionar propriedade em tempo de execução em uma classe já criada C#

Tags: c#

Preciso adicionar propriedades na classe GridDataSourceBase em tempo de execução, alguém pode me ajudar como fazer isso?

```
public class GridDataSourceBase : IGridDataSource
{
    public long Handle { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Procure por _Reflection_

Answer (score 1):

Uma hipótese é usar o [`ExpandoObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
dynamic objeto = new ExpandoObject();
objeto.Propriedade = 1;
```

Muito provávelmente terá que copiar as propriedades do objeto antigo para este objeto. Pode faze-lo da seguinte forma:

```
public static class DynamicExtensions
{
    public static dynamic ToDynamic(this object value)
    {
        IDictionary<string, object> expando = new ExpandoObject();

        var props = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(value.GetType());
        foreach (PropertyDescriptor property in props)
            expando.Add(property.Name, property.GetValue(value));

        return expando as ExpandoObject;
    }
}

var tuple = Tuple.Create(1, 1);
var newTuple = tuple.ToDynamic();
newTuple.Item3 = 1;
```

[Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13651190/how-to-extend-an-existing-object-in-c-sharp-4-0-using-dynamics)